# Plot from multiple files imported with glob

Tags: pandas, plot, graph, plotly, glob

I need to process hundreds of data files and I want to plot the results in a single graph. I'm using glob with a for loop to read and store the data, but I have no idea how to plot them with plotly.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly.express as px
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import plotly.io as pio
    import glob

    pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

    files = glob.glob('GIRS12_L_8V_0.95bar.*')

    traces = []

    for file in files:
        dat = pd.read_csv(file, sep='  ')
        dat.columns = ['time','v(t)'] 

        fig = go.Figure()
        traces.append(go.Scatter(x = dat['time'], y = dat['v(t)']))

    px.scatter(data_frame = traces)
```

Is it right to call px.scatter(...)? I was using fig.show() at the end but I don't know why it does not show anything in the graph.

Comment: do all of your CSVs have two columns?  (**time** and **v(t)**) do you want each file to be scattered as a separate color and have an entry in the legend?  (you note 100s of files, colors will be re-used, legend will become too long to comprehend).  **Plotly Express** is a higher level API than **graph objects** typically use one or the other,  px if API provides all capabilities you need to meet your visualisation requirement

Comment: Do you want the data from each file to show up as a separate trace on this one scatter plot? Or do you want to plot `v(t)` against `time` as one trace using the combined data from all of these files?

Comment: @DerekO : Yes I was wrong calling it scatter plot, I want to plot v(t) against time to have a line chart.

Comment: @RobRaymond: Yes all the files have two columns, and I don't mind about the legend at this point, since I only want to check if the data are reliable.

Comment: @Michele - so solution I provided below works.  just change to `px.line` if you want lines instead of scatter figure

Comment: @RobRaymond Thank you! It works, but it gives me also a minor issue I can't solve.

`dataframe = pd.concat(
        [pd.read_csv(f, sep='  ', index_col=0).assign(name = f.name) for f in p.glob("GIRS12_L_16V_0.95bar.*")]
        )
fig = px.line(dataframe, color="name",)
fig.show()` 

This is how I changed your code, to store the dataframe. I don't understand why the dataframe ends up having more than 2 columns while my input files have only 2.

Comment: `assign()` is creating an additional column **name** to keep which file the data came from so that a **color** can be used per file

Comment: I meant that it creates 12 columns more, I think because it reads 12 files. I don't understand why it happens, and what are the values in those columns.

Answer (score 1):

- have generated 100s of CSVs to demonstrate
- **pathlib** is more pythonic / OO approach to interacting with file system and hence `glob()`
- simplest approach with **plotly** is to use **Plotly Express** to generate all of the traces.  Have taken approach of preparing all data into a single **pandas** data frame to make this super simple
- per comments, a figure with so many traces and hence such a long legend may not be best visualisation for what you are trying to achieve.  Consider what you need to visualise and tune solution to achieve a better visualisation

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# location where files exist
p = Path.cwd().joinpath("SO_csv")
if not p.is_dir():
    p.mkdir()
# generate 100s of files
for i in range(400):
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "time": pd.date_range("00:00", freq="30min", periods=47),
            "v(t)": pd.Series(np.random.uniform(1, 5, 47)).sort_values(),
        }
    ).to_csv(p.joinpath(f"GIRS12_L_8V_0.95bar.{i}"), index=False)

# read and concat all the CSVs into one dataframe, creating additional column that is the filename
# scatter this dataframe, a scatter / color per CSV
px.scatter(
    pd.concat(
        [pd.read_csv(f).assign(name=f.name) for f in p.glob("GIRS12_L_8V_0.95bar.*")]
    ),
    x="time",
    y="v(t)",
    color="name",
)
```

[image]